# ember CLI - "Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events installing"

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, watchman

While using ember CLI, I get this:

`version: 0.1.5
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events`

I don't really care if it uses watchman or NodeWatcher ... - but I don't love this message - and I would like to use what ember wants me to. I installed watchman with homebrew... but still this message. Any ideas?

I am a version 3.0.0 with watchman - and 0.1.5 with ember.

When I `watchman watch ~/sites/mySite`

I get this 
`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpcre.1.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/watchman
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5`

Is this the ol - "brew putting things in unconventional spots" problem?

Comment: I updated with the suggestion that you run `brew install pcre`.

Comment: As of this date, 2500 people have viewed this, and 3 people upvoted it. That is pretty funny.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `watchman` isn’t properly installed. That error message indicates you’re missing `libpcre`; try running `brew install pcre`, what happens then?

As of Ember CLI 0.1.7, there’s [no longer a message when a valid version of `watchman` is found](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/commit/b086a7c4fb2469db2e98b1a4ad4ef7b14175c991#diff-9ff56008b40607a31bc04df7f41906cb).

Comment: Nice. Thanks. pcre wasn't linked properly due to a permissions error. All good now. : )